# Appcelerator - Newbie in the mix!

Tags: iphone, label, appcelerator

Quick one for any developers using appcelerator out there. I have two labels (This may even bew wrong) which are populated from an RSS feed. One label houses the title and another the description. The content for these comes from an RSS list which all works fine. THe issue I'm having is that some titles are longer than others so I cant fix label heights or it just wont work.

So with that in mind I set the titles height to be auto. The only problem is I cant reference this height from my second label to use the top: property to space it correctly.

Has anyone got any good suggestions?, Am I using the wrong type of Titanium UI method?

My current code is as follows

```
try
{
var current = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
var selectedItem = current.item;
var description = selectedItem.getElementsByTagName("description");
var story = description.item(0).text;


var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                    text:selectedItem.getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text,
                    left:5,
                    top:0,
                    height:"auto",
                    font:{fontSize:40}
                });
current.add(label);

var story = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                    text:story,
                    left:5,
                    top:label.height,
                    height:"auto"
                });
label.add(story);

}
catch(E)
{
 alert(E)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[minimumFontSize](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.Label-object#minimumFontSize)

the minimum size of the font when the font is sized based on the contents. Enables font scaling to fit and forces the label content to be limited to a single line

Answer (score 0):

On the containing window / view, set the layout property to 'vertical' - this means the views are stacked on top of one another so your top value doesn't have to know the height of the previous component.

```
// Windows
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: 'vertical',
    backgroundColor: '#FFF'
});

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width: 200,
    height: 'auto',
    text: 'some long text'
});

var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width: 200,
    height: 'auto',
    text: 'more long text',
    top: 10 // This just adds some padding between the two labels
});

window.add(label);
window.add(label2);

window.open();
```